# How to secure an variable so its not acessible by other code in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, authentication, iframe

currently I face the issue that I am building a modular Application that can run 3rd party Scripts within the interface, my concern now is that they grab the token and send over the Tab requests to the Server to steal Userdata. I had 3 Solutions in mind but I don't know if any of them is good, or if you maybe have a different Solution.

1. I put the entire App within an Iframe and set it to sandbox mode. The issue with this might be performance, Code difficulties and my App needs an Iframe anyways, so I would have at the end an Iframe nested within an Iframe.
2. I could generate a Token only for the editor, so for example that you have a specialized Token that can be used only for a few actions, and so by that, a bad code could not really do damage since they lack permissions.
3. (The approach I would prefer to do) I somehow store the token in a way that you cannot access it, but that prerendered functions can use it to interact with the server.

So any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: That's not possible. All code and all variables are accessible. Even the IFrame wouldn't change it.

Comment: @jabaa https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Comment: The IFrame has a `src` link. I can open that link and analyze the website in the IFrame. All data that has to be processed by the browser has to be accessible to the browser and the user of this browser.

Comment: Any code running in the browser should be considered public and readable.

Comment: @jabaa yeah thats true, but code cannot escape from the iframe outside of it, so I could for example store a variable on the actuall dom and run the dangerous code withhin the Iframe, but there is the performance concern.

Comment: I didn't know we are talking about dangerous code. I thought we are talking about secret tokens. There is no secret in frontend JavaScript. Of course, you can securely embed insecure external code but I don't how this relates to your problem.